# Why doesn't XMLHttpRequest doesn't like my JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

I created very very simple php program that takes data from a database and structures a php array, then it converts it to json:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $output[$i] = array();

  $output[$i]["tag"] = $row["tag"];
  $output[$i]["desc"] = htmlspecialchars($row["desc"]);

  if ($row["content"] != "") {
    $output[$i]["content"] = $row["content"];
  }

  if ($row["href"] != NULL) {
    $output[$i]["params"]["href"] = $row["href"];
  }

  $i++;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

echo json_encode($output, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

I was hoping to use this inside a codepen, linked here: http://codepen.io/mrcarter7/pen/pJMxzr

In this codepen I have the following javascript (from a tutorial found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
  console.log(this.status);
}

var url = "http://example.com/api/html";
// tutorial url: https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/kuma/contributors

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener('load', reqListener);
oReq.open("get", url, true);
oReq.send();
```

I want to map it to a javascript object to be used by the following logic in the javascript but ran into problems with that so I figured I'd keep it simple and just try to get it to output in the console and you'll see it doesn't but if you replace the url variable value with the URL from the tutorial linked above (sorry I can't post more than two links yet) it works fine!

Is there something wrong with my php/json? or is there an alternate way of taking the json from an external source and storing it as a local javascript object to be processed.

BONUS: Also, why is my json not formatted nicely like the tutorial's json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header to your API, else it cannot be accessed from other websites (like Codepen). [Enable-cors](http://enable-cors.org/) shows you how to do this with a variety of different languages.

The other major problem you have with the code provided is that it refers to the 'html' variable - which I expect is intended to be the object derived from your JSON - however it does not appear to be declared anywhere in the example. To get the 'html' variable, you would have to parse the response on the XMLHTTPRequest "load" event handler - and also move your existing code into that closure, as this code is executed asynchronously.

Your JSON isn't laid out in a 'pretty' way - but that's good, means you don't waste bandwidth dealing with formatting that the user will likely never see. It is, however, valid JSON - and you can verify this by pasting the output into JSONLint.

Comment: CORS is exactly what I was looking for to allow me to actually get the JSON in codepen. Oddly enough I also had to add the trailing "/" in my url variable in Javascript to get it to work. You are correct about the html variable. I'm working on that now. I'll approve your answer once I have it working. Standby. Thanks again for pointing me towards CORS.

Comment: Okay so after adding CORS and the trailing slash in my URL variable all I had to do was move my logic into the load event handler like you said because its executed asynchronously. After that I just had to declare my html variable and assign it the value of JSON.parse(this.response). (because response returns a string, not an object)

Can see it working at the codepen: http://codepen.io/mrcarter7/pen/pJMxzr